# Estruturação de Logs no Datadog com Java e Spring Boot

Tags: java, log4j2

Boa tarde 
Estou atuando em uma feature de estruturação de logs em java para envio ao Datadog e estou tendo alguns problemas com Logs em formato JSON, alguém já atuou em algo semelhante que possa dar algumas dicas de como fazer?

Consegui configurar o log4j2, logback e estruturar os logs em JSON, porém quando eu pego um objeto e faço "objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object)" ele fica formatado com "\" e acaba nao estruturando o objeto JSON no Datadog corretamente

Comment: Os caracteres "\" são escapes, para que seja possível manter as aspas na estrutura do json formatado como string (que é o que o método writeValueAsString faz). 
Você pode tentar uma abordagem assim: 
```java
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
String jsonUsers = mapper.writeValueAsString(users);
```